Trigger individual stages in different pipelines one after another
I have 2 pipelines: Infra and Code. Both share 1 code repository.
Infra is triggered when bicep code changes and azure resources must be redeployed.
Code is triggered when code changes and must be updated to function apps etc.
This is to reduce infra deployments when nothing changes, so run times get optimized.
Both pipelines have 2 stages: one for Dev env and one for Prod env.
Prod env has approval that I dismiss if I just want to test code in Dev.
Now, when infra changes the function app code gets wiped away and Code pipeline should be run always after it.
But if I dismiss the approval, infra pipeline does not complete and a pipeline trigger in code won't work
# infra pipeline yaml
stages:
- stage: Dev
  jobs:
  - template: 'deployInfraToEnv.yaml'
    parameters: ...

- stage: Prod
  jobs:
  - template: 'deployInfraToEnv.yaml'
    parameters: ...

# code pipeline yaml
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: Infra
      source: 'Infra pipeline'
      trigger: true # run after infra pipeline completes

stages:
- stage: Dev
  jobs:
    - template: 'deployCodeToEnv.yaml'
      parameters: ...
  
- stage: Prod
  jobs:
    - template: 'deployCodeToEnv.yaml'
      parameters: ...


Is it possible to somehow setup pipelines so that
Infra pipeline dev stage completes -> Run code pipeline dev stage
Infra pipeline prod stage completes -> Run code pipeline prod stage

Or should I just give up and integrate both infra and code deployments into one pipeline.

Do you expect the code pipelines triggered by the two situations of the Infra pipeline to be in the same pipeline run OR different Pipeline Run? And do you mean that Prod stage of the two pipelines both have approval step?

different pipelines (good for manual use) and single approval for Prod would be optimal, but 2 approvals is not a big deal

I misunderstood a bit.. same pipeline run for code would look good, not sure if thats possible?

So if I understood correctly, you have 2 scenarios:

Bicep code changes: redeploy infrastructure + code (Function App)
Application code changes: redeploy code (Function App)

I suggest using a separate pipeline for each scenario.
Pipeline 1 - Bicep code changes
Considering you are already using templates like deployCodeToEnv.yaml that can be easily reused across pipelines, you can keep things simple and use these templates in the first pipeline.
Something like:
# infra pipeline yaml
# When infrastructure changes deploy BOTH infra and code

stages:
- stage: DevInfra
  jobs:
  - template: 'deployInfraToEnv.yaml'
    parameters: ...

- stage: DevCode
  dependsOn: DevInfra
  jobs:
    - template: 'deployCodeToEnv.yaml'
      parameters: ...

- stage: ProdInfra
  jobs:
  - template: 'deployInfraToEnv.yaml'
    parameters: ...

- stage: ProdCode
  dependsOn: ProdInfra
  jobs:
    - template: 'deployCodeToEnv.yaml'
      parameters: ...

Pipeline 2 - Application code changes
Second pipeline stays basically the same, with the exception of the trigger (removed):
# When application code changes deploy code ONLY

stages:
- stage: Dev
  jobs:
    - template: 'deployCodeToEnv.yaml'
      parameters: ...

- stage: Prod
  jobs:
    - template: 'deployCodeToEnv.yaml'
      parameters: ...


Thats good, but can i somehow integrate an approval for Prod? I don't always want to update it

oh wait.. I think this would work perfectly. Thanks!

@tonsteri sure, you can add approvals and checks to any environment used (prod, dev, etc).

@tonsteri you can also deploy one and only one environment at a time - use a pipeline parameter named environment and based on that deploy set the right variables/environments.

@tonsteri also, keep in mind that you can skip prod stages when queuing a new build.

@tonsteri stages by default run sequentially, unless dependsOn property is set. Are you using templates for the stages as well? Are you able to see if that property is set and edit them?
Regarding jobs, they will run in parallel if both stages are started. You can use dependsOn on templates by adding a parameter to the template itself.

@tonsteri my proposed solution works for you, but obviously you need to set/fix the dependencies between stages according to your needs.

Again I was too hasty and didn't see you split everything in stages. Works just fine, accepted answer!

@tonsteri a bit off-topic. but you can set conditions, dependencies etc in templates - see Create Configurable and Extensible Jobs

thanks Rui, there's a bit code duplication and maybe conditionals could finetune this a bit
